# How to build a model to predict a graph (not a image) in time series?

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, artificial-intelligence

There is an adjacent matrix dataset that is based on time series. I would like to know if it is possible to build a neural network model to predict tn time point's matrix by using the previous time-series data. In my opinion, traditional models such as CNN may not fit for the sparse matrix graph.

Comment: you can use CNN to train on a time serie but you should reshape/rearange your data. For example if your data contains vectors you can concatenate them to a matrix. That means you only need to add a dimension to your data whichis time.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should give a look at Graph Neural Networks (specialy Spatial-Temporal Graph Networks). They use temporal information about graphs and its adjacency matrix to predict future nodes states, such values in the next-step.

You can read [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1901.00596.pdf) survey paper as a start point and follow its cited works therefore.